# Adding an ipad view after creating an iphone controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I know Xamarin supports universal iPhone/iPad views; however, after building some iPhone specific screens, it was mentioned about iPad support.  In Xamarin Studio, is it easy to add an iPad view attached to the same controller after the fact?  I know it uses an idiom to do the switch, as shown below (taken from [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_ipad___universal_apps)):

```
public Hello_UniversalViewController ()
        : base (UserInterfaceIdiomIsPhone ? "Hello_UniversalViewController_iPhone" : "Hello_UniversalViewController_iPad", null)
    {
    }
```

Within XCode, how can I then link all the same outlets and actions easily?  It seems possible, but looking for any guidance.  Or should I just delete them, then re-add them with the universal view?

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you should not delete your iPhone storyboard file instead you make one from file->Storyboard file and select for iPad. You can copy paste controllers from iPhone storyboard but then you have to set the dimensions and other relevant info specific for iPad.

hope this helps :)

Comment: I'll be attempting this tonight, so I'm about to find out :-)